# Ionic sidemenu not open in the Playlist page

Tags: ionic-framework

I did "ionic start myApp sidemenu" to start a sidemenu app. It starts with the "Playlists" page with 6 items. I click on one of those, say "Raggae" and it takes me to the "Playlist" page. At this point, the sidemenu does not open when I sweep from left to right.

In the following plnkr example from another StackOverflow question, the sidemenu does open after I nagivate to the "Playlist" page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width" />
    <title></title>
    <link data-require="ionic@1.0.0-beta.1" data-semver="1.0.0-beta.1" rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.1/css/ionic.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="ionic@1.0.0-beta.1" data-semver="1.0.0-beta.1" src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.1/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="starter">
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>

</html>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/0RXSDB?p=preview

Is this my local environment problem or something wrong with the sidemenu template code?

Comment: create your own plnkr plz with your code

Answer (score 1):

With a brute force method, I found out the ionic.bundle.js come with the "ionic start myApp sidemenu" is causing the problem. If I inlcude the ionic 1.0.0-beta.1 version as in the plnkr example, the problem is gone. But the beta version is causing other different behavior in navigation. Hopefully ionic gets better.